# What does the expression "You're just one more hand me down" in this song mean?

Tags: expressions, music

```
Someday they'll find your small town world on a big town avenue
Gonna make you like the way they talk when they're talking to you
Gonna make you break out of the shell cause they tell you to
Gonna make you like the way they lie better than the truth
They'll tell you everything you wanted someone else to say
They're gonna break your heart, yeah

[Chorus]

From what I've seen
You're just a one more hand me down
Cause no one's tried to give you what you need
So lay all your troubles down
I am with you now
```

Source: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/matchbox20/handmedown.html

Comment: [hand-me-down](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/hand-me-down) *a piece of clothing that someone has given to a younger person because they no longer want it*. Metaphorically, a *person* that the previous "owner" doesn't want any more. Second-hand goods, if you like. But that level of detail is Off Topic "lyrics interpretation" anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh so "hand me down" is a NOUN, right? I thought it was a verb somehow. They are missing the hyphens, correct?

Comment: Obviously it's a noun. You can tell that from your own context (which you've mis-transcribed - it's [*You're just one more hand me down*](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Music/Lyrics/Matchbox%2020/Hand%20Me%20Down.txt) without the ***a***). Most writers would hyphenate, but that doesn't make the cited usage "incorrect". Though for all I know the "original" did have hyphens - many "lyrics" websites are complete rubbish.

Comment: this question is simply "what does the idiom hand-me-down mean?"  The example happens to be in a song lyric; but there is no connection to "interpreting lyrics."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it would suggest that the person in question is someone who is used by others, and then discarded.  The next line supports this by suggesting that the person in question does not receive consideration from others, and in the next, the speaker is suggesting that despite the situation that has just been described, he is willing to offer a listening ear.

Answer (score 1):

*[hand-me-down](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hand-me-down)*: noun (informal) 
1.
something, esp an outgrown garment, passed down from one person to another
(as modifier): a hand-me-down dress
2.
anything that has already been used by another
(as modifier): hand-me-down ideas

so what the singer is saying when he says:

From what I've seen
You're just a one more hand me down
Cause no one's tried to give you what you need
So lay all your troubles down
I am with you now

he is saying you have been neglected and not valued but now with me you are no more.

Answer (score 0):

A hand me down is usually used to refer to something that has been used by someone else like an older sister or brother and then handed down to the next sibling in line.  While it can still be valuable to the family because they do not have to buy the item again, it is given to the next in line as used, rather than new.  In this case, it seems to mean someone no longer valued that has nothing new to offer.  I know that everyone is valuable because everyone has something to contribute, but this song does not seem to see this issue in the same light.